# How to match two files by characters and modify one file with python?

Tags: python, pandas, string

now i have two file, `file1` is the sequence file,and `file2` is the binding region with prediction score, `file1` look like:

| seq A | seq B |
| --- | --- |
| Q | Q |
| V | V |
| Q | Q |
| A | A |
| B | C |
| C | S |
| A | A |
| B | C |
| C | S |

another `file2` look like :

| id | region | score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| seq A | QABCA | 0.6 |
| seq B | CSACS | 0.4 |

now i want to match the prediction score tow the sequence(more than 100 sequence),the result i want is :

| seq A | seq A score | seq B | seq B score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Q | 0 | Q | 0 |
| V | 0 | V | 0 |
| Q | 0.6 | Q | 0 |
| A | 0.6 | A | 0 |
| B | 0.6 | C | 0.4 |
| C | 0.6 | S | 0.4 |
| A | 0.6 | A | 0.4 |
| B | 0 | C | 0.4 |
| C | 0 | S | 0.4 |

How could i get the result? Thanks!

I tried use `pd.str.match()`, but it it can't match in multi row same time.

Comment: `pandas` is not helping you here.  You should read the file(s) into a string, where you can do simple string searches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like that

```py
file1 = file1.reset_index()
file2 = file2.set_index("id")
for seq_id in file1.columns:
    region = file2.loc[seq_id, "region"]
    score = file2.loc[seq_id, "score"]
    seq = "".join(file1[seq_id].tolist())
    seq_start_index = seq.find(region)
    seq_stop_index = start_index + len(region) - 1
    file1[f"{seq_id} score"] = 0
    file1.loc[seq_start_index:seq_stop_index, f"{seq_id} score"] = score
```

Comment: I would have done more or less the same, just keep in mind that `str.find` only returns the **first** match, you might need `re.finditer` to get multiple matches :)